# Equal-width form labels with arbitrary horizontal rules

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal `label: <input>` style form. Labels need to be equal widths, but dynamic - based on the longest label in the form. Normally, I'd solve this with a series of `display: table/row/cell` elements, but we also need a horizontal rule separating *some* of these rows.

`display: table` does not play well with non-row/cell elements inside it.

The core form structure:

```
<form>
    <div class="group">
      <span>test</span>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="group">
      <span>test long</span>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <span>test</span>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { width: 100%; }

form {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.group {
  display: table-row;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}

input, hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The label widths work as I'd expect, yet the `hr` cannot fill 100% width. I can get the right width by making it `position: absolute`, but then I lose the spacing between the rows. I can make it a `display: table-row` but no longer have control over the spacing.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nululuquco/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Why not use `border-bottom` instead of the `hr`?

Comment: Because that doesn't allow us any control of the spacing before/after the separator which is essential, and our app is already using hrs in similar sticky situations. The only alternative I see is using a new class on the element *before* the separator and using an adjacent sibling separator to control the padding-top of the following element. Makes an ugly setup even more ugly but may be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

This was a funny one.

I don't know how much strict you are about the design but here is an ok solution.

```
hr{
  display:table-cell;
  padding:10px 0;
  border:none;
  box-sizing:content-box;
  background:black;
  height:1px;
  background-clip:content-box;
}
```

using `table-cell` on the `hr` you can expand it to full width, with a little trick on the `padding` and `background-clip` you can have a simple horizontal line. If you want to take it further you can add an image as a background and use `repeat-x` to expand it in full width.